# Find the angles of a triangle where m and n are positive integers

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I am trying to grok this but my lecturer did not provide a valid explanation. Can someone please assist or hint on how to solve this? Thanks.

The angles of a triangle are $\frac{π}{2}$, $\frac{π}{m}$ and $\frac{π}{n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers.

What values can $m$ and $n$ take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angles of a triangle add to $\pi$, so you need to find $m, n$ such that
\begin{align}
\pi &= \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{m} + \frac{\pi}{n}\\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{\pi}{2} &=\frac{\pi}{m}+\frac{\pi}{n}\\
\Leftrightarrow mn &= 2n + 2m
\end{align}
I think you can do the rest :)